# Pending and Cancelled Requests by Chrome after upgrade of PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iis

I face a problem where I have updated my PHP from **version 7.0.9** to **7.1.14** and now my page isn't properly loading. It has **.phtml and .php** files with jQuery code to execute.

> I use a Windows Server 2K12r2 64-bit with IIS.
>
> I have also pooling and intervals to query ajax response frequently (2 to 5 sec.).

Some requests went from pending into cancelled. Is there something I can double check in my PHP installation? It seems to be stuck within the .PHP files.

Thanks for suggestions.